Is this a mistake on Wikipedia on Standard Deviation?
On the Wikipedia page about standard deviation, in the section `Estimation', it says

Unlike in the case of estimating the population mean, for which the sample mean is a simple estimator with many desirable properties (unbiased, efficient, maximum likelihood), there is no single estimator for the standard deviation with all these properties...

However I think that the sample mean is not always the Maximum Likelihood Estimator for the population mean. For example, if we know that the population has a lognormal distribution, then it does not work.
Is this a mistake on Wikipedia?

You are right--but logically, Wikipedia is not asserting the sample mean is the MLE for all distribution families, only that it is an MLE: which it is for many families.  This is questionable exposition and questionable pedagogy, but it is correct.

How can this be rewritten for better exposition?

I could add 'in many cases'

I would not include "maximum likelihood" as a "property" at all.

I think the Estimator is also not efficient or unbiased in many cases

I don't know of any case where the usual SD estimator is unbiased; but the arithmetic mean of a random sample is always an unbiased estimator of the arithmetic mean: that's a consequence of linearity of expectation.

I found that the sample average is also not efficient in many cases. So it seems that the writer had normal distributions in mind.
